# How to run autokey on startup in Ubuntu 20 (FF)?

Tags: autokey

I am running some keyboard shortcuts on autokey in Ubuntu 20.04. How can I run the service automatically on startup?

Comment: Please clarify your release; Ubuntu using the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 20) are different products to the Ubuntu using *year.month* format (eg. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS); the former are *snap* only so confinement is more an issue meaning config differs somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

Autokey likely has an option in its Preferences to have it autostart when you log in. In general, usefull for applications that do not present such option, you can set that up yourself.

In the Activities overview, search "start". You will see the icon for the "Startup Applications" tool. Launch it by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> when the icon is selected.

Add your custom application using the "Add" button. The "Add Startup Program" dialog appears. It contains three fields. "Name:" and "Comment:" are for your reference only. "Command: " should point to the executable of the program you wish to autostart. You can type the full pathname. If the executable is within the search path (i.e., you can start it at the terminal only by typing its name), then also here, only the name will be sufficient.

To know the name of the executable, you need to check the documentation of the package. For Autokey, fill out `autokey-gtk` in the "Command: " field.